# Porting threads to windows. Critical sections are very slow

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, critical-section

I'm porting some code to windows and found threading to be extremely slow. The task takes 300 seconds on windows (with two xeon E5-2670 8 core 2.6ghz = 16 core) and 3.5 seconds on linux (xeon E5-1607 4 core 3ghz). Using vs2012 express.

I've got 32 threads all calling EnterCriticalSection(), popping an 80 byte job of a std::stack, LeaveCriticalSection and doing some work (250k jobs in total).

Before and after every critical section call I print the thread ID and current time.

- The wait time for a single thread's lock is ~160ms
- To pop the job off the stack takes ~3ms
- Calling leave takes ~3ms
- The job takes ~1ms

(roughly same for Debug/Release, Debug takes a little longer. I'd love to be able to properly profile the code :P)

Commenting out the job call makes the whole process take 2 seconds (still more than linux).

I've tried both queryperformancecounter and timeGetTime, both give approx the same result.

AFAIK the job never makes any sync calls, but I can't explain the slowdown unless it does.

I have no idea why copying from a stack and calling pop takes so long.
Another very confusing thing is why a call to leave() takes so long.

Can anyone speculate on why it's running so slowly?

I wouldn't have thought the difference in processor would give a 100x performance difference, but could it be at all related to dual CPUs? (having to sync between separate CPUs than internal cores).

By the way, I'm aware of std::thread but want my library code to work with pre C++11.

**edit**

```
//in a while(hasJobs) loop...

EVENT qwe1 = {"lock", timeGetTime(), id};
events.push_back(qwe1);

scene->jobMutex.lock();

EVENT qwe2 = {"getjob", timeGetTime(), id};
events.push_back(qwe2);

hasJobs = !scene->jobs.empty();
if (hasJobs)
{
    job = scene->jobs.front();
    scene->jobs.pop();
}

EVENT qwe3 = {"gotjob", timeGetTime(), id};
events.push_back(qwe3);

scene->jobMutex.unlock();

EVENT qwe4 = {"unlock", timeGetTime(), id};
events.push_back(qwe4);

if (hasJobs)
    scene->performJob(job);
```

and the mutex class, with linux #ifdef stuff removed...

```
CRITICAL_SECTION mutex;

...

Mutex::Mutex()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&mutex);
}
Mutex::~Mutex()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&mutex);
}
void Mutex::lock()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&mutex);
}
void Mutex::unlock()
{
    LeaveCriticalSection(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: What were you using on Linux? Are you protecting only the access to the std::stack with the critical sections?

Comment: Where do you print the thread id and current time to?

Comment: Pick a language. And this does seem odd. It certainly *sounds* simple enough for an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to be workable. I concur my experience on Windows has been somewhat lackluster compared to a comparably equipped Linux distro, but this really seems a pretty wide chasm.

Comment: I was using pthread_mutex_lock on linux. The CS lock/unlock covers if(!jobs.empty()){job=jobs.front(); jobs.pop();}. I print to the console, but can try to a file if you think it'd make a difference.

Comment: It would be sufficient to redirect the output to a file. I'm betting it's the console that's slowing you down.

Comment: 3ms to pop an 80 byte struct?

Comment: Could you show your timing code? Out of curiosity, have you tried mutexes instead (which are expected to be inherently slower)?

Comment: In fact, all the code would be 'interesting'.  What do the threads wait on for stack entries, condvar, semaphore?

Comment: Have you tried using `std::mutex` and `std::lock`? Which results do you get?

Comment: OK, I've stored events with time and print after the jobs are done, just using timeGetTime and getTimeOfDay. On linux, all operations happen within microseconds (lock,pop,unlock = running in parallel) and on windows lock still takes ages and I'm back in the milliseconds realm. The code is a raytracer and is too big to post all of it (see edit). I was hoping for some ideas of how to debug where my time is being lost.

Comment: @ogni42 using std::mutex gives a 10x boost to the speed vs CRITICAL_SECTION. Now it takes 25 seconds, still not as fast as linux though.

Comment: @Noseratio Timing is pretty much a single call on either platform. I don't know how to get an accurate time on windows - apparently queryperformancecounter gives incorrect values with multithreaded apps. However it's so slow that timeGetTime is giving an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Changing the stack to use pointers makes no difference on the speed. It seems more and more likely that windows CRITICAL_SECTION is simply dead slow with my current compiler configuration.

Comment: A guess: Your problem might be the spinning done while entering the critical section. If many threads try to enter the critical section, they'll all spin and try to get the lock. As you've more threads than can be concurrently run, the producer thread might be blocked by this. You could try adjusting the spin count using either [SetCriticalSectionSpinCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) or [InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css).

Comment: @jozxyqk, for timing I'd just do `Enter/LeaveCriticalSection` alone in a x10000 loop and measure the time-lapse. Then would do the same in linux and compare.

Comment: I've been playing with critical sections, changing the spin count (or implementing a spin myself), windows mutexes and std mutexes. Also reducing the number of threads helps a lot. They all give the same speed of 16 seconds total now - still slower but within the same range at least. There was one point where a printf was still printing even though it was commented out and a clean solution fixed it. It took 24ms to enter/leave 1million times. Could it be the timing code is simply at fault and the job just takes much longer on windows with the VS compiler and a slightly slower CPU?

Comment: Seems like you also include the `push_back` in your timing. Did you reserve enough capacity not to trigger an allocation?

Comment: @DyP no, I didn't reserve anything, but I tested the total time commenting out the timing code. When looking at the events I'm pretty sure allocation would be happening so infrequently it wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Are you are polling this CS-protected queue with all 32 threads?

Comment: Yes, but the threads have a lot to do in-between polls. On linux there is zero contention most of the time - it's only there to stop the odd collision. On windows, the locking takes so much time it creates contention, as far as I can tell. Anyway, I think it might be something to come back to at a later date. Thanks all for your input!!!

Answer (score 1):

Window's CRITICAL_SECTION spins in a tight loop when you first enter it. It does not suspend the thread that called EnterCriticalSection unless a substantial period has elapsed in the spin loop. So having 32 threads contending for the same critical section will burn and waste a lot of CPU cycles. Try a mutex instead (see CreateMutex).

Comment: [I suspect the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442574/porting-threads-to-windows-critical-sections-are-very-slow#comment27103010_18442574), but wouldn't adjusting the spin count be more appropriate / faster than using a mutex?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your windows threads are facing super contention. They seem totally serialized. You have about 7ms of total processing time in your critical section and 32 threads. If all the threads are queued up on the lock, the last thread in the queue wouldn't get to run until after sleeping about 217ms. This is not too far off your 160ms observed wait time.

So, if the threads have nothing else to do than to enter the critical section, do work, then leave the critical section, this is the behavior I would expect.

Try to characterize the linux profiling behavior, and see if the program behavior is really and apples to apples comparison.

Comment: I agree, they appear to be running loosely sequentially (occasionally there is a little difference in the execution order). There is no code to serialize them, and a 80 byte copy and pop should be WAY WAY faster than my job. What really doesn't make sense is the time taken to call LeaveCriticalSection. I believe the serialization is a symptom of an underlying issue with critical sections. I will double check the contention on linux though.